# AWS DMS for CDC - Avoid creating new databases/tables

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-dms, change-data-capture

We need to sync a `users` table on one database instance (MySQL) to a `users` table on another database instance (Aurora/MySQL 8) in real time by using `CDC` (change data capture).

We use multitenancy, so we have a ton of schemas (databases) on the source like `schema_1`, `schema_2`, `schema_3`, etc. Each of these schemas has it's own `users` table.

I want these users tables synchronized in real time to the target, but *only* if the schema and `users` table already exists on the target database. I do *not* want to create new schemas on the target.

One reason why I don't want these schemas and tables to be created is that the `users` table on the source has a bunch of columns that I do not need on the target. Another reason is that this would complicate database migrations (schema migrations through code).

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have it set to:

| Option | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Migration Type | Replicate data changes only |
| Table preperation mode | Do nothing |

The table mappings are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "891714557",
      "rule-name": "891714557",
      "rule-target": "schema",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "dev1_schema_%"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-prefix",
      "value": "aurora-db_",
      "old-value": null
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "selection",
      "rule-id": "891590357",
      "rule-name": "891590357",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "dev1_schema_%",
        "table-name": "users"
      },
      "rule-action": "include",
      "filters": []
    }
  ]
}
```